# What happens when a creature with vulnerability to a damage type has resistance to the same type imposed on it, or vice versa?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, vulnerability

So, let's imagine for a moment that two Fiend-patron Warlocks are fighting. One uses its Fiendish Resilience to get resistance to fire damage, but the other one casts the Hallow spell with the Energy Vulnerability effect to impose vulnerability to fire damage.

The description of the [Fiendish Resilience](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheFiend) feature:

> **Fiendish Resilience:** Starting at 10th level, you can choose one damage type when you finish a short or long rest. You gain resistance to that damage type until you choose a different one with this feature. Damage from magical weapons or silver weapons ignores this resistance. *(PHB 109)*

And the extra effect of [Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow):

> **Energy Vulnerability:** Affected creatures in the area have vulnerability to one damage type of your choice, except for bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing. *(PHB 249)*

Which trumps which in this scenario? Or do they cancel out and result in standard (1x) damage?

Also, bonus points:

- If imposed vulnerability/resistance trumps innate vulnerability/resistance, how does it interact with immunity?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76457/discussion-on-question-by-seraphswrath-what-happens-when-a-creature-with-vulnera).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### They both apply (*almost* 1x damage).

On page 197 of the Player's Handbook, it states (bolds added):

> Resistance **and then** vulnerability are applied after
> all other modifiers to damage.

This means that you would apply resistance, and then vulnerability to damage, in that order. **This often would mean that you would only take the normal (x1) amount of damage**: but not always. Note that on page 7 of the PHB, it states:

> There’s one more general rule you need to know at the outset. Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater.

As such if the damage dealt was odd (eg, 15) first it would be halved, by resistance, rounding down (eg, to 7 from 7.5). This halved damage would then be doubled by vulnerability  (eg, increasing it to 14).

DMs might ignore this fringe case, as it can only result in a 1 point damage difference. But it is an accurate feature of the rules as written.

As far as Immunity goes,  Vulnerability/Resistance both apply to enemies who also have Immunity, but to no particular effect. After all, halving or doubling 0 will still result in 0.

Comment: Thank you. You also indirectly answer the "next step" question about Immunity (2x 0 is still 0) if I'm reading the answer correctly as well, and your answer was more complete. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

This is answered on page 197 of the PHB:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

But they essentially cancel each other out anyway. If a creature that has both resistance and vulnerability to fire damage takes 20 fire damage it's first halved to 10 then doubled back up to 20.

In the case of immunity and vulnerability, applying them in tandem will result with a zero, either way (immunity first or last). But the correct order is to leave vulnerability last.

Immunity sets the damage to zero, then vulnerabilty doubles the zero, for  a net total of zero damage. Effects that trigger on damage taken won't happen, but effects that depend on a hit will.