# Can someone with vulnerability to necrotic damage benefit from resistance, in regards to the Evocation wizard's Overchannel feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, damage-resistance, vulnerability

Overchannel ([Evocation Wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofEvocation) feature) states that the necrotic damage it deals ignores immunities or resistances to its damage - but something like vulnerabilities would still be applied.

If I am vulnerable to necrotic damage, then gain resistance to necrotic damage, do I:

- Receive normal damage from Overchannel as the two void each other?
- Ignore my resistance and deal double damage from being vulnerable?

Comment: Is this purely theoretical or do you have a way for a vulnerable creatures to gain resistance? Adding a specific example would improve your question.

Comment: Mostly theoretical, but the Wish spell has one of its explicit options as "Up to 10 creatures you choose gain Resistance to the damage type you choose".

Comment: How did the wizard become vulnerable to necrotic?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [What happens when a creature with vulnerability to a damage type has resistance to the same type imposed on it, or vice versa?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121086/what-happens-when-a-creature-with-vulnerability-to-a-damage-type-has-resistance)

Answer (score 12):

## You would be vulnerable to the damage

The second half of the Overchannel feature states:

> If you use this feature again before you finish a long rest, you take 2d12 necrotic damage for each level of the spell, [...] This damage ignores resistance and immunity.

It only ignores resistance and immunity, not vulnerabilities. Though multiple resistances and vulnerabilities to the same damage type will usually cancel each other out, this isn't always true. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/112528/48759) supports that both would be applied if you had them.

The rules on damage resistance and vulnerabilities only mention cases where you have multiple sources of resistance, these do not stack and would be ignored in this case anyway. The best rule it gives us is:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

So first you would apply your resistance, which is ignored, then your vulnerability. The result is you take double damage from this feature.

Answer (score 2):

## Resistance will not be applied

From PH 197:

> Resistance and **then** vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

This means that Resistances are applied first (if applicable) then Vulnerabilities (if applicable).  Since Resistances are not applicable in this circumstance, the creature will gain no benefit from Resistance.

The end results of Vulnerability and Resistances may balance out to no change in most circumstances (x0.5 and x2.0), but that does not mean that they inherently void one another out (like with Advantage vs. Disadvantage).